# Strange interaction between type families and incoherent instances

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, type-families

This code sample doesn't compile.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module IncoherentBug where

type family F a where
    F () = Int
    F a = a

class C a where
    c :: a -> Int

instance C Int where
    c y = y

instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} Monoid a => C a where
    c _ = 0

class TwoPossible a where
    x :: a

instance a ~ () => TwoPossible [a] where
    x = []

instance TwoPossible Bool where
    x = False

f :: (F a -> Int) -> [a] -> ()
f _ _ = ()


test = f (\v -> c v) x
```

Basically what's happening here is the signature of `f` requests that the type of `x` gets resolved to `[()]`, then the type of `v` is `F ()` which is `Int`, and finally the first instance of `C` should be picked. What happens instead is that I get a missing `Monoid Int` instance error.

The code compiles fine when I change the `INCOHERENT` instance to an `OVERLAPPABLE` one. It also works if I annotate `v` with either `Int` or `F ()`. It also works if I annotate `x` (as the parameter to f) with `[()]`.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something here? ghc-mod reports the type `F ()` for `v` even if I don't annotate it as such. Besides the fact that the error message mentions an `Int` means that the type checker figured out the correct type for `v` but for some reason didn't pick the more specific instance.

I should also maybe note that I'm using GHC 8. I don't know if this issue appears in the earlier versions.

Comment: Presumably GHC is selecting an instance for `C` early on, which it's entitled to do since the instance it selects is marked `INCOHERENT`.

Comment: @ReidBarton Wouldn't that make incoherent instances pointless since it basically means "always pick this instance"?

Comment: Incoherent instances are useful when you want `instance C X y` and `instance C x Y`, and you don't care which instance is chosen for `C X Y`. Overlapping instances are useful for making me look at your code like a dog turd on my shoe.

Comment: @dfeuer Apparently you also have to not care which one is chosen for `C Z W` either.

Comment: No, that is quite irrelevant. Your `INCOHERENT` instance is completely general; you have no type constructors in it.

Comment: @dfeuer That's not how the process is supposed to work. If two instances match then the more specific one gets picked. If there's more than one most specific instance then `INCOHERENT` pragma has an effect.

Comment: I don't think that's right, no. I believe only the overlapping stuff and not the incoherent stuff cares about specificity. But I can't say I'm sure, because the documentation is horribly complicated and simultaneously vague. These are just awful extensions that should really be ripped out like invasive ivy.

Comment: @dfeuer I'd agree that https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=incoherentinstances#ghc-flag--XIncoherentInstances leaves things a bit open to interpretation but I'm pretty sure that one of these instances should get eliminated before any of these pragmas become relevant.

Comment: Like I said earlier, I think instance resolution for `C` is happening before GHC knows anything about the type `t` of `v` will be. So the instance `C Int` is not even a candidate since it does not match `C t`. Since there is an instance `C a` to select that is incoherent, GHC does not care about the fact that `t` might later turn out to be a type for which there is a more specific instance available. This is documented in the section you linked to.

Comment: @ReidBarton I don't think it's sensible that adding a type annotation to something for which GHC already knows the type should change if the code compiles. Ultimately what I'd want is to have an instance that gets picked if the type is polymorphic so it's not possible to determine which concrete instance to pick. What I get here is GHC giving up before it absolutely has to. I guess it just doesn't work like that but it sure seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC is completely correct to reject this code. You have a `C (F a)` constraint which arises from

```
f c :: C (F a) => [a] -> ()
```

When you turn on `INCOHERENT` , GHC will immediately reduce this to

```
f c :: Monoid (F a) => [a] -> ()
```

*without even considering the type of the argument*. That is what incoherence means - an instantiation could provide a more specific instance, but an incoherent instance matches anyways. And of course the instance `... => C a` matches *every* type, so if your `C` constraint appears anywhere, that instance will be matched immediately.

With `OVERLAPPABLE` or the like, the `C (F a)` constraint *cannot* be reduced by selecting the `Monoid a => C a` instance, because the `C Int` instance could match as well (this is coherence, the opposite of incoherence).

If you want to see yourself, ask GHC for the inferred type of `f c` with `INCOHERENT` and `OVERLAPPABLE`.

Comment: You are completely right. Seems that GHC immediately solves as much as it can when it gets to `f c` when `x` is yet to be applied. In fact, if I switch the order of arguments of `f` then my code works and the second instance is selected.